# storing a value before nullifying a rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok, im new to ruby and rails, I cant seem to get which I would assume to be simple working. Basically my code is to remove a reference to an association (nil it).

I want to get the name member (Team.name) of the model and save it to (team_name) before removing the association for the flash message.

Here is the controller action and Models:

```
def remove_resource
    ...
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    team_name = @user.team.name
    @user.team = nil
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "<a href=\"#{user_path(@user)}\">#{@user.name}</a> was removed from "+team_name+". They are no longer on a team."
      ...
    end
    ...
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many   :user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_id", 
                       :order => "team_start"

    ...

    def ==(another_team)
        if self.name != another_team.name then 
          return false
        end

        if self.location != another_team.location then
          return false
        end
        ...
        true
    end

    ...

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :team,  :class_name => "Team", 
                       :foreign_key => "team_id"

    ...
end
```

The Errors I am receiving:

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#remove_resource

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

The trace:

```
app/models/user.rb:50:in `=='
app/controllers/teams_controller.rb:50:in `remove_resource'
```

Now the error only occurs when I retrieve the

```
@user.team.name
```

If I delete this and the reference to the variable team_name, all works fine.
Thanks!

Comment: What if you do:     team_name = "#{@user.team.name}"

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because you dont have the `@user.team` associated anymore. There is only a `nil` which doesnt have the Model specific method `name`. So you need to validate if threre is a team associated or not before executing methods of a associated object that may not be there.

```
def remove_resource
    ...
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    if @user.team.nil? # Check if theres a associated object
        #do sth. when theres no team to remove
    else
        team_name = @user.team.name
        @user.team = nil
        if @user.save
        flash[:notice] = "<a href=\"#{user_path(@user)}\">#{@user.name}</a> was removed from "+team_name+". They are no longer on a team."
      ...
    end
    ...
end
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. I've been doing some more research with no avail. If I remove the "@employee.line = nil" then no error, the same if I remove the "line_name = @employee.line.name"
It looks as if the equality operator is called for some reason, I was hoping some light would be shed on this

Comment: Gregor, I really doubt you are getting the same error after following davidb's advice.  The `if @user.team.nil?` should ensure that `@user.team` is not nil inside the `else` clause.  Double check your stack trace to see what line the error is happening on.  You can also use puts, pry, or the ruby debugger to get more insight into what is happening in your code.